# Filtering samples by FORMAT attributes using bcftools

Tags: vcf, snp, filtering, bcftools

The `-e` and `-i` options of the `bcftools filter` command appear, by default, to only allow for including or excluding *sites*.  E.g., `-e 'FMT/DP < 10'` removes sites where any sample has `DP < 10`, and `-e 'MEAN(FMT/DP) < 10'` removes sites where average depth across samples is < 10.

I would like to perform effectively similar filtering commands, but in a way that includes or excludes samples, instead of sites.  E.g., exclude all *samples* that have `DP < 10` at any *site*, or exclude all samples with an average depth across all sites < 10, or exclude all samples that have a genotype quality of < 20 at 10% of genotyped sites.

Such commands can very easily be written to apply to sites, but there does not seem to be a straightforward way of applying such filtering expressions to samples in `bcftools`.

One option mentioned in the manual is to use the double `||` operator, as described in the [man page](http://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html#expressions).  As described in my [comment](https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/issues/1384#issuecomment-770082770) on a Github issue, however, this does not seem to work as a filtering operation for including or excluding entire columns in a VCF file, but rather only for selecting more or less individual records (e.g., as illustrated in the example on [this tutorial page](http://samtools.github.io/bcftools/howtos/filtering.html)).  In addition, it would seem limited in functionality (e.g., functions such as `MEAN(FMT/DP) < 10` would still be evaluated across samples, not sites, when combined with a `||` operator).

The only other method mentioned in the manual is to use the `SMPL` or `s` prefix to functions which evaluate `FORMAT` fields in expressions passed to `filter`.  This also does not appear to work as I would expect.  I'm not sure I understand what it *is* doing, but it definitely *isn't* removing columns from the VCF file.  Instead it seems to be using as a metric calculated across sites on a per sample basis as a filtering criteria applied to sites (but I could just be confused):

```
nSites_unfiltered=$(bcftools view -H unfiltered.vcf.gz | wc -l) 
nSamples_unfiltered=$(bcftools query unfiltered.bcf.gz -l | wc -l)

nSites_DPfilter=$(bcftools filter unfiltered.bcf.gz -e 'sMEAN(FORMAT/DP)<5' | bcftools view -H | wc -l)
nSamples_DPfilter=$(bcftools filter unfiltered.bcf.gz -e 'sMEAN(FORMAT/DP)<5' | bcftools query -l | wc -l)

echo "scale=5; $nSites_DPfilter / $nSites_unfiltered" | bc #0.17349 - sites are removed, even though the filter is being applied to samples
echo "scale=5; $nSamples_DPfilter / $nSamples_unfiltered" | bc #1.00000 - no samples removed, despite, again, the filter being applied to samples

nSites_normalDPFilter=$(bcftools filter unfiltered.bcf.gz -e 'MEAN(FMT/DP) < 5' | bcftools view -H | wc -l)
echo "scale=5; $nSites_normalDPFilter / $nSites_unfiltered" | bc #0.83121 - fewer sites removed than the sMEAN filter
```

The `.bcf.gz` passed to these commands is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwj1snabsb763sn/unfiltered.bcf.gz?dl=0
Its `.csi` index file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzdq6y91nkencmy/unfiltered.bcf.gz.csi?dl=0

In any event, the only option I have been able to come up with that actually excludes or includes entire sample IDs is to extract summary statistics using `bcftools stats`, export the desired statistics from the `PSC, Per-sample counts` table, and perform my own exploratory analysis outside of `bcftools`.  Then I can use `bcftools view -S` to explicitly remove samples by their ID, which I have identified manually as failing some thresholding criteria.  This also is obviously cumbersome, and only works for `FMT` fields that are included in `stats` (e.g., not `GQ` or `PL`).

I am not sure if I am missing some basic functionality of `bcftools`, or if this is more of a feature request.  Any information would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to take a look at vcftools' genotype filtering options or the custom JEXL expressions that GATK's SelectVariants allows. Are you sure your sample-filtering operations won't produce a variable number of columns for each row? Also, remember that `bcftools filter` will not remove samples no matter what you try. It's a utility to filter sites, and it can only filter sites.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Since every site has genotypes for every sample (if you include missing genotype entries), I'm not sure I understand how removing certain columns in their entirety would create any problems in terms of uneven dimensions.  Indeed, this is the function of `bcftools view -s ^<list.of.sample.IDs>`, if I am not mistaken.  `vcftools` also only allows for filtering samples based on ID.  Thank you for the reference to SelectVariants.  Do you have a link to a manual, or example code to address any of the example use-cases referenced in my question?  Thanks!

Comment: Not really, no. I have rarely ever used SelectVariants when it wasn't already implemented in a pipeline (GATK tools can be a pain to use at times). If push comes to shove, it might be worth converting the VCF to MAF format so the data is at individual level.